# Bootstrap 4 - Line up element containers across columns to have equal heights

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

Using Bootstrap 4 row and columns is it possible to line up all the elements to equal container heights for each section like header and image so everything lines up in each column?

Example:
[image]

I'm mostly concerned with lining up the images and possibly cropping them if needed. The image tag src will come from an api call so I'm not sure if I can add them as a background for the container.

Not sure what the best way to go about this would be...

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="container-fluid product-section" id="productSection">
    <div class="row card-row">
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="001">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading single line</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/tech" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="002">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading double line of text copy and info</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="003">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading single line</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/people" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="004">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading with three lines of copy and information to try and line up.</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/350/animals" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this how you want??

```css
h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-img-container .rounded {
    border-radius: .25rem!important;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="container-fluid product-section" id="productSection">
    <div class="row card-row">
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="001">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading single line</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/tech" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="002">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading double line of text copy and info</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="003">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading single line</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/people" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-col col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="004">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h5>Heading with three lines of copy and information to try and line up.</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://placeimg.com/300/350/animals" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-description">
            <p class="text-muted">
              See Description<span class="float-right">+</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="af-button-group">
            <div class="af-link">
              <p>Link 1<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 2<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 3<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
              <p>Link 4<span class="float-right">More</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That'll work for what I am trying to do. But I wonder is there a way to use flexbox and stretch or grow the containers across columns?  It would be good to show all of the heading if possible as well.

Comment: flex only adjust the width not the height.